# Exception in Hibernate Configuration

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, jdbc

I am very new to Spring, Hibernate. while working on hibernate I am facing the following problem. I also searched related tags on stackoverflow, but couldn't found any relevant post that solved my issues.

**Student.java File**

```
package hibernatepractise;

    public class Student {
        private long id;
        private String name;
        private String degree;
        private String phone;



        public Student() {
            super();
        }

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getDegree() {
            return degree;
        }

        public String getPhone() {
            return phone;
        }

        public void setId(long String) {
            id = String;
        }

        public void setName(String string) {
            name = string;
        }

        public void setDegree(String string) {
            degree = string;
        }

        public void setPhone(String string) {
            phone = string;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }

}
```

**AddStudent.java File**

```
package hibernatepractise;


import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import hibernatepractise.Student;

public class AddStudent {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        // begin if
                                                                    // A
            String name = "Jayesh Vyas";
            String degree = "B.tech Completed";
            String phone = "9421345678";

            System.out.println("Name: " + name);
            System.out.println("Degree: " + degree);
            System.out.println("Phone: " + phone);

            if ((name.equals("") || degree.equals("") || phone.equals(""))) {
                System.out.println("All informations are Required");
            } else {

                try {// begin try
                    sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
                    // sessionFactory1 = new
                    // Configuration().configure("com\\xml\\student1.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("mathan");
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed."+ e);

                }
                Session s = sessionFactory.openSession();
                // Session s1 =sessionFactory1.openSession();
                // Transaction tx1= s1.beginTransaction();
                Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
                Student stu = new Student();
                stu.setName(name);
                stu.setDegree(degree);
                stu.setPhone(phone);
                s.save(stu);
                tx.commit();
                System.out.println("Added to oracle Database");
                if (s != null)
                    s.close();

                // Student1 stu1=new Student1();
                // stu1.setName(name1);
                // s1.save(stu1);
                // tx1.commit();
                // System.out.println("Added to mysql Database");
                // if (s1 != null)
                // s1.close();
            }
       // }// end of if A
    }// end of method
}// end of class
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="studentFactory">
        <property name="connection.driver_class">
            oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
            </property>
        <property name="connection.url">
            jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:test
        </property>
        <property name="connection.username">
            system
        </property>
        <property name="connection.password">
            manager
        </property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">5</property>
        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
            </property>
        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <mapping resource="Student.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Student.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="hibernatepractise.Student" table="studentOracle1">
        <id name="id" type="long" column="ID">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" column="name" not-null="true" />
        <property name="degree" column="degree" />
        <property name="phone" column="phone" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**I am facing the following errors in my code**

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:29)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:420)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1326)
    at hibernatepractise.AddStudent.main(AddStudent.java:42)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:480)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:413)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:508)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:203)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:33)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:510)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:417)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:361)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:966)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:292)
    ... 13 more
```

I know that there is a silly mistake in my code but I am not able to find out as I am new to hibernate so that's why i request you to please help me to get out from this problem.
I shall be highly thankful to you for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what error do you get? do you have a stack trace to share?

Comment: hey I add the errors in the above questions.

Comment: yes and: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39605087/exception-in-thread-main-org-hibernate-exception-genericjdbcexception-cannot

Comment: I am using eclipse as IDE.

Comment: your IDE has nothing to do with it. It is just an advanced text editor

Comment: I saw the post, but the suggestions in the  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661610/tns-12505-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-descript  are not related to my question. @ScaryWombat

Comment: @JayeshVyas can you upload your code to github ?

Comment: Yes sure @AmitKhandelwal

Comment: hey @AmitKhandelwal please refer https://github.com/JayeshVyas/error-in-hibernate-configration.git

Comment: @JayeshVyas , thaks i'll take a look.

Comment: @JayeshVyas , how you are running it, I don't see any hibernate specific jars included, also its not a maven project.

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal i am running using eclipse IDE and I already added all the necessary jar file in my project.

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal if i am running using default database(XE) then it will add data into database and works fine. I think it is creating problem when i am working with the database named test.

Comment: @JayeshVyas, this is not a proper way to doing the things. better to convert it as a maven project , its difficult to debug with your current setup.

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal Ok thanks Amit, I will try :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the error lies in this line:

`jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:test`. I think it should be 
`jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/test`

A `/` instead of a `:`

Comment: I already tried it, but it didn't help me. :-(  @Jack Flamp

Comment: @JayeshVyas see update

Comment: I tried this also, but it didn't help. hey if I am using the port 8088 then ???

Comment: @JayeshVyas Should probably not matter. but what do I know? I have never worked with Oracle db

Comment: hey jack it is working when i am using default database(XE), creating problem with the database i created named test.